# How to capture mouse drag events in YouTube 360 videos using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is there a way to capture the event when navigating the screen by dragging on a YouTube 360 video?

I would like to obtain the x, y, and z coordinates of the video's current viewing direction.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

It seems that I couldn't find a way to do it, even after researching.
If there is a hint, please let me know.